# Increment Hebrew characters for list and psuedo elements

Tags: html, css

I have two cases here: increment hebrew characters with list style and with psuedo elements. It looks fine but for > 9, with pseudo elements the hebrew character is reversed. For example: 11 is shown as אי  instead of  יא.

May I know how can I get the exact same behavior with pseudo elements like I get with list.

**List style type hebrew**

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: hebrew;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

**Increment Hebrew characters for pseudo elements:**

```css
ol {
    text-align: right;
    counter-reset: num;
    float: left;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: num;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}
li:before {
    content: '.' counter(num, hebrew);
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    right: -35px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I do not get that char for 10, I get it for 11 in iOS Safari

Comment: Why do you have `direction:ltr` in the `li:before`?

Comment: mplungjan Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It is for 11 only. I edited my question.

Comment: Mr Lister That was for some layout I was using earlier. But it is not necessary in this case. So, I removed them from my question.